# Angular: Testing HttpMock with multiple parameters expectOne() fails

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a service in Angular which takes 3 parameters. [I had issues with HttpParams using append() so I just used the fromObject parameter in the constructor. May look weird but for now it works.]

Service code

```
getData(paramOne: string, paramTwo, string: paramThree: number): Observable<Object[]> {
  const obj = {};
  obj['p1'] = paramOne;
  obj['p2'] = paramTwo;
  obj['p3'] = paramThree;
  let params = new HttpParams({fromObject; obj});
  return this.httpClient.get<Object[]>('myurl', {params: params})
}
```

This works.  On the server side I can get parameters out of the request.  No issues.

However, in the unit test with HttpMock(), I do have issues.

```
// httpMock = new TestBed.get(HttpTestingController)

it('should get data', (done) => {
  const data = {};
 // populate simulated return data

 service.getData("param1", "param2", 3).subscribe(data => {
  // tests here
 });

 const req = httpMock.expectOne('myurl?p1=param1&p2=param2&p3=3');
 expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
 req.flush(data);
 httpMock.verify();
});
```

the httpMock.epectOne() call fails

```
Expected one matching request for criteria "call to api", found none.
```

I've tried this with zero and 1 parameters and the pattern works.  I've checked for typos and whatnot.  Irksome... anything I'm missing or a way to get a closer look at what the URL actually turns in to?

Comment: what is httpMock' type, it should be HttpTestingController

Comment: It is -- sorry.  Thought that was in there.

Comment: If I remove `done` parameter in callback(`it('should get data', (done) => {`) then your test works for me

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, order isn't guaranteed in an object correct?  Looking over the docs I'm assuming I need to use one of these overloads: https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController#expectOne

Comment: @yurzui the reason it passes w/o the done() is b/c it's not being run.

Answer (score 0):

So, the actual problem in this case was that I had a double-byte character in the URL and it was URL encoded on the other side.  I running a test against a literal.  Quite frustrating.  I was able to figure that out by following a suggestion to use a matchFunction in [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19974) which has a good example.